# Looking to display non-image files in Gallery with logo specific to file type

Tags: customization, uploads, gallery

When I first began looking into this, [File Gallery](http://skyphe.org/code/wordpress/file-gallery/) got me much closer to solving the problem. The only issue is that the plugin only displays the generic non-image icon when I upload a file.

Does anyone know of a pre-existing plugin that would either work alongside File Gallery or in place of it to achieve logos specific to a file type (say, I upload a .doc file then the plugin displays a MS Word logo).

Failing a pre-existing plugin, what would be a good starting point to attempt to craft my own hand-made solution?

Thanks in advance!

*Note: This was originally posted in on the wordpress.org support forum [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/looking-to-display-non-image-files-in-gallery-with-logo-specific-to-file-type), but since it got no responses there, I thought I'd try my luck here.*

Comment: Just to follow up on this, following finding a solution to this I developed the [Document Gallery plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/document-gallery/) so if anyone else has a similar issue they are welcome to give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordPress has a native function `wp_mime_type_icon()` in `wp-includes/post.php` that you can use.

Basic example:

```
// $attachment should be a full post object 

if ( wp_attachment_is_image( $attachment->ID ) )
{
    echo wp_get_attachment_image(
        $attachment->ID,
        array( 480, 900 ),
        FALSE,
        array ( 'class' => 'aligncenter' )
    );
}
else
{
    echo '<img src="' . wp_mime_type_icon( $attachment->post_mime_type ) . '">';
}
```

Look in `wp-includes/images/crystal/` for available file type icons:

- archive
- audio
- code
- default
- document
- interactive
- spreadsheet
- text
- video

[image]

You can set up your own image directory and filter `'icon_dir'` for the local path and `'icon_dir_uri'` for the URIs to let WordPress use your images.
To change just singular files filter `'wp_mime_type_icon'`:

```
apply_filters( 'wp_mime_type_icon', $icon, $mime, $post_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will have luck getting it to work with another gallery plugin without altering that plugins code, but you can do this yourself rather easily by writing a plugin/function or using a template page.

What you can do is use `get_children` to grab the `post_mime_type`, in your case a simple example would be,

```
get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=doc' );
//assuming your using ms .doc files.
```

Once you have the mime type you can use `wp_get_attachment_link` to create the link, unfortunately this functions `$icon` parameter is a boolean so it does not allow you to add your own icon, you will have to `echo` out an actual url to the icon you want to use.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_link
http://tgrayimages.com/automate-file-attachments-on-your-wordpress-posts/